# How do I code a web button that stops/breaks an infinite loop Rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, infinite-loop

The title is fairly self-explanatory. I want to build an always-on rails script, which is easy. I also want the user to be able to break the loop via a web interface, alter parameters, and restart. How do I achieve this?

Standard caveats apply - I'm sorry for being such a noob, and I definitely googled this hard, only to get a load of results about <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: How do you plan to start the script? This may affect how you turn it off.

Comment: At the moment, I'm providing a link to a static page which triggers a method from a helper. I'm very open to better suggestions.

Comment: Could you describe the context of why you need this? It sounds like an usual situation. Perhaps there's a better approach that can be suggested.

Comment: The script interacts with Twitter's API, and fires as many requests as the API's rate limits will allow (which isn't many). I guess a better alternative would be to fire a script every 15 minutes via a cron job/heroku scheduler... Still curious, though - is there any way to break a rails process without terminal commands?

Comment: It sounds like you're planning to run the task synchronously, thus making the web server block. The request will time out, either in the client or in the server. What you should do is perform the work asynchronously, for example via a job queue. To stop the job you could have the job poll a shared data store. The web client sends requests to start and stop the job.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm way out of my depth here; would i be right in thinking that something like Delayed Job would be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a lightweight solution, you can put this initializer into `config/initializers`:

```
class MyLoop
  def initialize
    @stop       = false
    @semaphore  = Mutex.new
  end

  def self.instance
    @@instance ||= new
  end

  def start
    @semaphore.synchronize do
      @thread = Thread.new do
        loop until @stop
      end
    end
  end

  def stop
    @semaphore.synchronize do
      @stop = true
      @thread.join
      @stop = false
    end
  end

  def restart
    stop
    start
  end

  def loop
    #call your twitter service here
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize) do
  MyLoop.instance.start
end
```

Call your twitter service in the `loop` method. Then you can define actions in your controller which will stop or restart the loop:

```
def stop_twitter_service
  MyLoop.instance.stop
  render nothing: true
end

def restart_twitter_service
  MyLoop.instance.restart
  render nothing: true
end
```

Your button on the page should make an AJAX request to these actions.

Note that this loop will also start when you run the rails console or any other command which loads the application.